# sort directory by substrings in python

Tags: python

Assume: I have directory name: dir1
Dir1/

```
A_Y2016W25
A_Y2017W15
B_Y2017W30
A_Y2016W20
B_Y2017W35
A_Y2017W30
```

I want to sort it by YXXXX and by WXX and print this in order:

```
A_Y2016W20
A_Y2016W25
A_Y2017W15
A_Y2017W30

B_Y2017W30
B_Y2017W35
```

How can I use with sort ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please try to write the code first and post some samples for more help.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = ['A_Y2016W25', 'A_Y2017W15', 'B_Y2017W30', 'A_Y2016W20', 'B_Y2017W35', 'A_Y2017W30']
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
['A_Y2016W20', 'A_Y2016W25', 'A_Y2017W15', 'A_Y2017W30', 'B_Y2017W30', 'B_Y2017W35']
```

Will do the job.

In fact you have no need to perform a substring of any kind, because you already have left to right precedence in the sorting you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by -

```
a = ['A_Y2016W25', 'A_Y2017W15', 'B_Y2017W30', 'A_Y2016W20', 'B_Y2017W35', 'A_Y2017W30']

def ext(strng):
    return ord(strng[0]), int(strng[3:7]), int(strng[8:])

a.sort(key = ext) #['A_Y2016W20', 'A_Y2016W25', 'A_Y2017W15', 'A_Y2017W30', 'B_Y2017W30', 'B_Y2017W35']
```

Comment: This is overengineered a basic sort() will do the job for the OP's issue in his context.

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using `sort()` with a based regex key function like this example:

```
import re 

def sort_regex(regex, a):
    data = re.search(regex, a)
    return data.group(0) if data else ''

a = ['A_Y2016W25', 'A_Y2017W15', 'B_Y2017W30', 'A_Y2016W20', 'B_Y2017W35', 'A_Y2017W30']

a.sort(key=lambda x: sort_regex(r'Y\d{4}', x))
print(a)

a.sort(key=lambda x: sort_regex(r'W\d{2}', x))
print(a)

a.sort(key=lambda x: sort_regex(r'Y\d{4}W\d{2}', x))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['A_Y2016W25', 'A_Y2016W20', 'A_Y2017W15', 'B_Y2017W30', 'B_Y2017W35', 'A_Y2017W30']
['A_Y2017W15', 'A_Y2016W20', 'A_Y2016W25', 'B_Y2017W30', 'A_Y2017W30', 'B_Y2017W35']
['A_Y2016W20', 'A_Y2016W25', 'A_Y2017W15', 'B_Y2017W30', 'A_Y2017W30', 'B_Y2017W35']
```